# Failed to load pdf file when uploaded on server. Codeigniter hmvc

Tags: php, codeigniter, pdf

i have this show uploaded pdf file on my localhost my view is

```
<?php
  // retrieve your info ecc.
  $url = $content->PATH;
  $filename = $content->FILE_NAME;
  header('Content-type: application/pdf');
  header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="' . $filename. '"');
  header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
  header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
  @readfile($url);
?>
```

just to be clear

`$content->PATH` and `$content->FILE_NAME` are data from database

`$content->FILE_NAME` is  `$file_name = $file_data['file_name'];`

and `$content->PATH = base_url().'uploads/pdf/'.$file_name;`

now it perfectly works on my localhost, but on the server, it looks like this

[image]

the link to this is

```
 $row[] = '<a href = "http://146.88.72.53/CaloocanCity/PDFuploads/pdffile/'.$info->ID_NUM.'/'.$info->DOC_NO.'/'.$info->FILE_NAME.'" class = "btn btn-sm btn-info pull-left fa  fa-question-circle" title="Show File">&nbsp Show File</a>";
```

what is the error of this ? how can i solve this?

Comment: Maybe its fault of permission?

Comment: echo path of the pdf file on server....is base_url set?

Comment: what is this "fault of permission"??

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND yes the base_url is set

Comment: What permissions you have set for the file, folder, etc.?

Comment: @rad11 where is this permissions? on the codeigniter or the server?

Comment: Where you do not work on localhost you wrote that it works so enter this place where the project now is it

Comment: Did you check for http or https? File should be availabe to others with read permissions.

Comment: @rad11 i cant understand please explain briefly.

Comment: @MangeshSatheIND where is this read permission? on server or on my codes?

Comment: go to your cPanel and change permissions. Stranded permissions are Files: 644
Folders: 755  ...........(OR just for testing try first 777/755 *****after testing change 777and755)

Comment: my permissions are 777

Answer (score 2):

Try with CI built-in download helper class

`$this->load->helper('download');
force_download($file_name);`